# How to make a horizontal scrolling menu in Game Maker Studio 1.4?

Tags: android, game-maker, touch, menu

I know how to place the items you see in the picture, my problem is how do I move them? How do I know if the player is swiping right or left? I made the items with a `ds_list` in a script file and then have an object `obj_MenuCreation` run that script, so if I move the `obj_MenuCreation`, will it move the list with it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [Device Input functions](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/mouse,%20keyboard%20and%20other%20controls/device%20input/index.html), finding out if the user is swiping left or right shouldn't be much hard.

In the documentation, about the function [`device_mouse_x()`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/mouse,%20keyboard%20and%20other%20controls/device%20input/device_mouse_x.html), it says that the returned value *"for mobile devices (...) will only be updated while the screen is being touched"*. You can use this function in a *Step Event* to get the last *x* value of the mouse (the finger on mobile devices).

Let's say we have two variables, `cur_x_new` and `cur_x_prev`, and we updated them in a *Step Event* as follows:

```
// Step event - Update cursor input
cur_x_prev = cur_x_new;
cur_x_new = device_mouse_x(0);
```

We can then define three different cases:

- **Equal values:** the user isn't moving the finger on the screen or, more likely, they aren't even touching the screen at all;
- **New value greater than previous:** the user moved the finger towards right since the last update;
- **New value smaller than previous:** the user is moving the finger towards left.

The swiping "speed" can be calculated as `cur_x_new - cur_x_prev`, and you can also check for this value to be at least greater than a threshold, otherwise you can assume no swipe action is occurring.

**Edit**
Once you know whether the user is swiping, you can move the sprites by drawing them at *coordinates + offset*, where *offset* is a clamped value that increases/decreases depending on the swiping direction.